# MySQL INSERT SELECT problem

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-error-1062

I have a table with primary key `id AUTOINCREMENT` and many columns where `lang='en'` and so if I do:

```
DELETE FROM ".MY_PRF."form WHERE `lang` <> 'en';
```

I want to copy all the columns where `lang='en'` and then changing `lang` to `'cz'` like so:

```
INSERT INTO form (`lang`, `caption`, `type`) 
  SELECT 'cz', `caption`, `type` 
    FROM form 
    WHERE lang = 'en';
```

This query produces an error:

```
Duplicate entry '127' for key 1
```

I don't know what's happening because the primary key is `AUTOINCREMENT`. I just want to duplicate the `lang='en'` rows changing the `lang` to `'cz'`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error 1062 - Duplicate entry '127' for key 'PRIMARY' - can't find the reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15251267/error-1062-duplicate-entry-127-for-key-primary-cant-find-the-reason)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what is the type of ID variable?

If it is TINYINT change it to the INT