# Error 1062 - Duplicate entry '127' for key 'PRIMARY' - can't find the reason

Tags: mysql

I'm getting this error:

> #1062 - Duplicate entry '127' for key 'PRIMARY'

and can't find the reason.

The query  :

```
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('00');
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('01'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('02'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('03'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('04'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('05'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('06'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('07'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('08'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('09'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('0A'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('0B'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('0C'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('0D'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('0E'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('0F'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('10'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('11'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('12'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('13'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('14'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('15'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('16'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('17'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('18'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('19'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('1A'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('1B'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('1C'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('1D'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('1E'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('1F'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('20'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('21'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('22'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('23'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('24'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('25'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('26'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('27'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('28'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('29'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('2A'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('2B'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('2C'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('2D'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('2E'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('2F'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('30'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('31'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('32'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('33'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('34'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('35'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('36'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('37'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('38'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('39'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('3A'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('3B'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('3C'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('3D'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('3E'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('3F'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('40'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('41'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('42'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('43'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('44'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('45'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('46'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('47'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('48'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('49'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('4A'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('4B'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('4C'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('4D'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('4E'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('4F'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('50'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('51'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('52'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('53'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('54'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('55'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('56'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('57'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('58'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('59'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('5A'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('5B'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('5C'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('5D'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('5E'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('5F'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('60'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('61'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('62'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('63'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('64'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('65'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('66'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('67'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('68'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('69'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('6A'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('6B'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('6C'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('6D'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('6E'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('6F'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('70'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('71'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('72'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('73'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('74'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('75'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('76'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('77'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('78'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('79'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('7A'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('7B'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('7C'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('7D'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('7E'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('7F'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('80'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('81'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('82'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('83'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('84'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('85'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('86'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('87'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('88'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('89'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('8A'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('8B'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('8C'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('8D'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('8E'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('8F'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('90'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('91'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('92'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('93'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('94'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('95'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('96'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('97'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('98'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('99'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('9A'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('9B'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('9C'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('9D'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('9E'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('9F'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('A0'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('A1'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('A2'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('A3'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('A4'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('A5'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('A6'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('A7'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('A8'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('A9'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('AA'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('AB'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('AC'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('AD'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('AE'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('AF'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('B0'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('B1'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('B2'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('B3'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('B4'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('B5'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('B6'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('B7'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('B8'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('B9'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('BA'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('BB'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('BC'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('BD'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('BE'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('BF'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('C0'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('C1'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('C2'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('C3'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('C4'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('C5'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('C6'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('C7'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('C8'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('C9'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('CA'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('CB'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('CC'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('CD'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('CE'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('CF'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('D0'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('D1'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('D2'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('D3'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('D4'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('D5'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('D6'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('D7'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('D8'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('D9'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('DA'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('DB'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('DC'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('DD'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('DE'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('DF'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('E0'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('E1'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('E2'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('E3'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('E4'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('E5'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('E6'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('E7'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('E8'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('E9'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('EA'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('EB'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('EC'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('ED'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('EE'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('EF'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('F0'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('F1'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('F2'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('F3'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('F4'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('F5'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('F6'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('F7'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('F8'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('F9'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('FA'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('FB'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('FC'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('FD'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('FE'); 
INSERT INTO `portautomadb`.`tag` (`codigo`) VALUES ('FF');
```

the table's structure :

```
CREATE TABLE `tag` (  
    `idtag` tinyint(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
    `codigo` varchar(3) NOT NULL,  
    PRIMARY KEY (`idtag`),  
    UNIQUE KEY `codigo_UNIQUE` (`codigo`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=127 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

need help thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

signed `TINYINT` can contain numbers frmo -128 to 127. You most likely already have 127 rows in your table, so your primary key column can't contain more. Change your datatype do `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` (0-65535) `MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED` (0-16777215) or just `INT UNSIGNED` (0-4294967295) - that lasst one should be more than enough

Comment: Actually Bill's is more accurate

Comment: +1 to you as well @Mchi - you posted yours a few seconds before I posted mine.  FYI, I am told by MySQL developers that internally, MEDIUMINT storage is always rounded up to 4 bytes anyway, so there's no advantage to using it unless you really want to restrict the range of your column.

Comment: @Mchl I think both are accurate :)

Answer (score 6):

Your primary key is a TINYINT (signed 8-bit integer), which can only take values up to 127.  If you try to insert the 128th row, the new auto-increment value is truncated to 127, and this fails because there's already a row with that value.

Alter your table to change the data type of idtag to INT:

```
mysql> alter table tag modify column idtag int auto_increment;
```

Whereas altering a column is an expensive operation in a very large table, it should be very fast in this case, because by definition your table has at most 127 rows in it.

Comment: Saw Mchl's answer first; +1 as well.

Answer (score 2):

You have reached the maximum value of the `TINYINT` datatype which can hold from -128 up to 127. Change it to `INT` instead.