# MySql 1062 error that has me scratching my head

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1062

I created table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
  `ID` tinyint(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SKU` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `Title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Description` text NOT NULL,
  `Price` decimal(3,2) NOT NULL,
  `Image1` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Image2` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Keywords` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `Shop` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
  `lmlCat` tinyint(3) NOT NULL,
  `VinylCat` tinyint(3) NOT NULL,
  `FancyCat` tinyint(3) NOT NULL,
  `Active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `SizeDescription` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Size` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
);
```

When importing data from CSV, it imports 127 lines then I get this error:

```
#1062 - Duplicate entry '127' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Comment: *How* are you importing the data from your CSV?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [1062 Mysql - can't find the reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15251267/1062-mysql-cant-find-the-reason)

Answer (score 6):

You made the `ID` column a `tinyint` which can only take values from -127 to 127, larger values are truncated. Make it a regular `int` and things will work.

Comment: There's really no reason to use `TINYINT` in 2014. Three bytes per row is not going to end your database.

Comment: Yep it hit me about 30 seconds after I posted...DOH!  sometime you can not see the wood for the trees