# Broken auto_increment on primary key?

Tags: mysql

I have no idea how to fix this, I've dumped and recreated the database (per an answer somewhere else), tried manually inserting 128 ... and tried just deleting 127 and tried again. :/ Can't figure it out.

```
Copied this from the query I just tried:
INSERT INTO  `bestofthebest2`.`Topics` (`topicid`, `category`, `topic`)
VALUES ('128', '', ''), (NULL ,  '',  '')
MySQL said: Documentation

#1062 - Duplicate entry '127' for key 'topicid'
```

Comment: Also tried deleting the entire id column and re-adding it as primary, auto_increment ... That bought me a few more rows because of some that I'd deleted but, stopped again right at 127

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error 1062 - Duplicate entry '127' for key 'PRIMARY' - can't find the reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15251267/error-1062-duplicate-entry-127-for-key-primary-cant-find-the-reason)

Answer (score 2):

Is the data type of `topicid` a `TINYINT` by chance? The maximum value a signed tinyint can hold is 127. Additionally, MySQL has a rather odd (in my opinion) overflow behavior in that it simply rounds down overflows rather than erroring. What's happening is that it's trying to increment to 128, but that overflows, so it gets changed to 127. Since 127 already exists, it errors.

This can be easily recreated:

```
CREATE TABLE test ( id TINYINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY );
INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES (128);
-- A select will show you a row with id = 127
INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES (128);
-- ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '127' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

The simplest fix is to use a bigger data type. A signed integer will afford you 2^31-1 values, so unless you plan on having more than 2 billionish topics, it should work well:

```
ALTER TABLE bestofthebest2 CHANGE topicid topicid INT NOT NULL;
```

Comment: It's like you were reading our conversation on the other answer ;)

Comment: @trex005 I actually got lucky (in a twisted way) in that I ran into this a while back. I had a table that had an int primary key get to the maximum value, and after a long moment of staring at a very weird error message, I realized the 'duplicate' key happened to the maximum value of a signed integer. MySQL really should error in this case instead of rounding down :/.

Comment: You're a genius! 
Here I was just wildly deleting the table and recreating it thinking I'd get a different result. :) Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

First:

```
SELECT MAX(topicid)+1 FROM `bestofthebest2`.`Topics`;
```

Then with the result as $RESULT:

```
ALTER TABLE `bestofthebest2`.`Topics` AUTO_INCREMENT = $RESULT;
```

Comment: Maybe I did it wrong?
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$RESULT' at line 1

Comment: You need to plug in what you got as your result from the first query in the place of $RESULT in the second query.  I tried to give it to you as a subselect, but my MySQL would not accept a subselect for an ALTER TABLE query.

Comment: It didn't return any rows.

Um ... I think I messed it up bad now. I thought maybe I'd delete the id and try to finish getting the topics in and then add it but ...

#1062 - ALTER TABLE causes auto_increment resequencing, resulting in duplicate entry '127' for key 'PRIMARY' 

How in the world does this happen? Is it going to do this on my other tables? UGHHHH

Comment: SELECT MAX(topicid)+1 FROM `bestofthebest2`.`Topics`; does not return any rows?

Comment: Unless I'm not understanding or doing it right. Now I can't even add a primary key. I hate this project. lol.

I don't understand why it would be stopping at 127 or "resequencing"

Comment: That would lead me to believe that you either 1) have no data in the table (which would not lead to a duplicate entry) 2) have a corrupted table 3) have some sort of user error (sorry)

Comment: I'm sure that it is user error. There are 149 total rows, I was leaning towards a corrupted table but, I'd deleted and rebuilt the database. Is there a reason why it wouldn't want to auto_increment above 127?

I tried to open a chat but still can't.

Comment: Yes, it would not be able to extend past 127 if topicid was a tinyint